# Camera preview is black when using getExternalStorageDirectory to save the video

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm capture video using [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API and [Google sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video).

I come up against an issue when I trying change output location to be saved on the `sdcard/MyApp/filename` instead `Android/data/my_package/filename`.

Here is the method:

```
private File getVideoFile(Context context) {
    // Not working, cause black preview
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                                                    "/myApp/", "myVideo.mp4");
    // Working
    return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "myVideo.mp4");
}
```

So, my question, why saving the video on the sdcard cause "Black preview" and how can I save the video on the sdcard ?

### Edit

Here is the permission I ask:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Is the video itself written to the desired location?

Comment: @AlexCohn, not sure I understand you, in 'getVideoFile' I ask to save the video in the location I want. you can click on the google example link to see the full code. Thank you !!

Comment: No, it's me who probably did not understand you. You said, "the preview is black". I thought you were speaking about the preview that you see on the screen while recording. Is this is case?

Comment: yes, is the case, the preview that should show what the user is recording is black when I using `getExternalStorageDirectory` but not with `getExternalFilesDir`

Comment: So my original question was, if the video was recorded to the file (when the preview was black)? Was the file created at all?

Comment: @AlexCohn, no the file wasn't created (and it's crashing the app)

Comment: Does your APK have the permission to write to external storage? If this all happens on Marshmallow, be careful with the new dynamic permissions system!

Comment: Yes, As far as I know. I add the permissions section to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I don't know why it's like this, but the preview is blank when the target directory is not exist.

I save the video in `myApp` directory that wasn't exist yet, that's cause the preview to be blank.

The solution is to create the directory first and just than to save the video. The code should be like this:

```
private File getVideoFile(Context context) {
    File folder = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myApp/");
    folder.mkdirs();
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myApp/", "myVideo.mp4");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save video on SD card (Secondary external storage) use this API: [getExternalFilesDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)).

This API will return array of paths of external storage and secondary external storage respectively. Second path is SD card path. Some devices can have 2 SD cards as well, so it would be better to check if "sdcard" keyword in returned path. To know the difference between various storages check my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427958/631803) answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I receive one path only (for data-package). In additional,  I success to retrieve to correct path, using `getExternalStorageDirectory` just I haven't permission