# Questions about Android storage capacity

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, capacity

I have a question about the storage concept of Android.

Once you have an external storage called SD card. And we use cell phone capacity as built-in storage.

At this point, the built-in storage is divided into internal storage and external storage. The internal storage is a system area that can only be accessed by apps,

External storage is a shared area that can be accessed by users or other apps.

The question I have mentioned is, if the Galaxy S8 has 64GB capacity, it will be a built-in storage. If so, I wonder where the external storage and the internal storage occupy each of the 64 GB, and where can I see them? Are both stores sharing 64GB? And please explain if there are any deficiencies or additions in my explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> If so, I wonder where the external storage and the internal storage
>   occupy each of the 64 GB, and where can I see them?

You can see it in **Settings > Storage > Internal Shared Storage**.

Below is screenshot from Sony Xperia Z5 device Android 7.1:

[image]

> Are both stores sharing 64GB?

Yes both are sharing the storage. Check below screeshot from **Settings > Storage**:

[image]

To understand more about stoarge capacities in Anroid you can check my famous answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427958/631803