# what means the "External Storage " and " Internal storage" for Android devices

Tags: android

For android devices System I found two types of memory storage there we can  save our application data, the **External** and the **Internal** storage, I want to know  the physical difference between them ? Is the SD card storage and the internal device storage?

Comment: You can see the [Android storage guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) for more explanations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences among Internal storage, external storage, sd card and removable storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092591/what-are-the-differences-among-internal-storage-external-storage-sd-card-and-r)

Comment: I have a series of blog posts on what [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) mean.

Answer (score 0):

yes the sd card is external storage or any other device storage which is plugeed to your mobile eg. usb drive , and the internal is the device main storage