# Android App Specific Files and Shared Storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-storage

I have always thought the following code store my document files in mobile's **INTERNAL** storage until I realized the variable `state` always returned as **mounted**, then I realized I was totally wrong. The documents been storing on "**EXTERNAL**" storage. Whereby this external storage does not necessary mean Removable/SD Card. It's actually my mobile's storage (Example, 64 GB Mobile Storage) *(Please correct me if I'm wrong)*

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        File path = (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) ?
          new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), options.getString(DIRECTORY)) :
          new File(mReactContext.getFilesDir(), options.getString(DIRECTORY));
```

I'm aware they are 2 different kind of storage as follow:

- [App Specific Storage - External](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-verify-availability)
- [Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#use-cases)

Here's my questions:

1. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal) ...

> When the user uninstalls your app, the files saved in app-specific storage are removed.

...  Looking at my code, my app is storing the documents using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, don't this means all the documents are stored under app-specific storage? Because when I try to uninstall my app, the folder is not being remove. Why is that?

(Here's the path of the directory **/storage/emulated/0/myFiles** by the way)

2. If I'm correct, question #1 does not actually store under app-specific storage instead it's stored under **Shared Storage** (which I think it's consider as External Storage as well?). However looking at the Shared Storage link I shared on top just now, shouldn't my code be using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to create and store a new document?
3. Do we usually store the files within Internal storage or External (SD, Non-Removable Storage)? The non-removable storage here I meant is, the internal storage on your mobile phone (Example, 64GB internal memory my Mobile Phone). Referencing the [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092591/what-are-the-differences-among-internal-storage-external-storage-sd-card-and-r/38700948#38700948).

Subpoint:
It seems that there are total of 4 methods we can use for storing
[Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

**More details as followed:**

file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="myFiles" path="." />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Comment: App specific directories are for instance getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir and getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: That's true when you are trying to access different location for storing data on within app specific directories. If you will refer to the link [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-select-location)