Listing files in Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera from Android app
I'd like to create an application for myself for easily categorize my previously taken pics. As I'm digging into this, I've found some forum posts relating to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but there's no similar refering on Internal Storage. Some posts about the impossibility of this, but I have some exteral file-browsing apps installed, like Total Commander, which can successfully read the whole storage regrdless it's external or internal. How is that possible? Any ideas?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092591/what-are-the-differences-among-internal-storage-external-storage-sd-card-and-r

"there's no similar refering on Internal Storage" -- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is for what users see as "Internal Storage". From an SDK standpoint, it is referred to as "external storage" for historical reasons.

Thanks for explaining it @CommonsWare, it was confusing, but it become clear for now!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
